# Rejecting a suggested edit twice breaks the error message

Tags: bug, review, edits, suggested-edits

If you open up a suggested edit review twice in two different windows, and attempt to review it in both, ordinarily it will display an error message, explaining why you can't review it the second time:
[image: Expected]

However, if you try to reject the edit in both windows, the error message box does not get displayed correctly:
[image: Bug]

This only seems to happen if both are rejections. Approving in both acts as though both reviews succeeded, and reject->approve or approve->reject will display an appropriate error message.

Obviously it's not a problem very often, but it is pretty confusing when it happens.